# Discord.py role membercount

Tags: discord

I'm looking for a way to let the discord API return the number of members of a role so I can count that and later add that to a nickname. does anyone have any idea how to do this? I've been looking all day and it looks like there is a way but the documentation doesn't refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enumerate though the server members and roles, adding them to a list if they have the role:

```py
for member in server.members:
    for role in member.roles: 
        if role.name == "somename":
            add_it_to_some_list
```

See: https://www.reddit.com/r/discordapp/comments/8yvq4g/get_all_users_with_a_role_using_discordpy/